# App performances poorly and crashes on device but not on emulators and not showing exceptions

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have an Windows Phone 8.1 store project, it runs well on the emulators however when I tested it on my device (Lumia 930), it runs slowly and crashes to start screen a lot.

Even worse when it crashes the debugger still thinks it's running and not showing any unhandled exceptions or any errors. I had to manually stop debugging. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Did you try it on another device ? your device might have a problem for example low storage or something else.

Comment: Check and make sure you have requested all the required permissions in the manifest.  The emulator is much more forgiving of these type errors than a phone

Comment: I just tried some other apps and I found out they also run slowly on my phone but not on emulator according to the permanency analysis tool (horrible draw speed on xaml elements), Is that a normal thing or there's something wrong with my phone?